# Replace nan value dynamically in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to replace `NaN` values in the below pandas `df` column with two separate values i.e 8 and 12.

```
  |  ColumnD   |
  +------------+
  |    6       |
  |    NaN     |
  |    10      |
  |    NaN     |
  |    14      |
```

I'm currently able to achieve this manually using `iloc` of the data frame like below :

```
df.iloc[1:2, 0] = 8
df.iloc[3:4, 0] = 12
```

Is there a way, wherein I can replace the `NaN` values (with 8 and 12) by adding 2 to the previous value of Nan's and not directly replacing the `NaN` with 8 and 12 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use np.where to conditionally fillna

```
df['ColumnD']=np.where(df['ColumnD'].isna(),df['ColumnD'].fillna(method='ffill')+2, df['ColumnD'])

    ColumnD
0      6.0
1      8.0
2     10.0
3     12.0
4     14.0
```